# Django: handle migrations for an imported database?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-database

I'm working in Django 1.8 and trying to set up an existing project. I've inherited a database dump, plus a codebase.

I've imported the database dump successfully.

The problem is that if I try to run `migrate` against the imported database I then get errors about columns already existing, because the database is already at the end state of all the migrations:

```
 django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "managing_group_id" 
   of relation "frontend_pct" already exists
```

How can I resolve this?

I would like to be able to add new migrations from this point, and I would also prefer not to delete all the existing migrations.

Basically I need a way to say "skip straight to migration 36, and continue from there".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`--fake`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake) option to tell Django that each app in the database has already been migrated to a particular migration. For example, for the app that has been migrated to migration 36:

```
./manage.py migrate --fake myapp 0036_your_migration_name
```

You'll have to do this for each installed app.

Comment: Phew! Thank you :) For anyone wondering, the `--fake` flag goes at the end of the command above.

Answer (score 1):

I think your migrations problem solved by the previous Answer. Therefore I'm adding a link below...

If you just started django 1.7 and above then

Here I'ld like to add a link [Django Migration How works](https://markusholtermann.eu/2014/09/django-17-database-migrations-done-right/)

That will useful where I think.